# How to include canceled Adwords account user credential to invited account?

Tags: google-ads, users, accessibility

I need share my AdWords account with another user therefore, as AdWords usual way I send him an invitation.

From his end he cannot activate the AdWords shared account with his current Google credentials. When he does following error message is displaying

"A Google Account can only have access to one AdWords account. 
The Google Account `xxxx@gmail.com` already has access to an AdWords account. "

I understand the above error meant but he claimed to say that he already cancelled his AdWords account which mean no longer exist.
As a solution he can create new user login info only to access AdWords account but since he's going to be feature administrator of our AdWords account he's hesitating use that option.

So anyone could anyone help me on this?

Comment: I've had this problem myself in the past. Never got it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem myself.   The only solution appears to be to create a separate Google account.

Google does have the [AdWords My Client Center](https://www.google.com/adwords/myclientcenter/) that can be used to manage multiple AdWords accounts, but you can only sign up for it if you don't already have an AdWords account.

I use my browser's private browsing features to sign into the separate Google account when I need to manage AdWords.